# NoneType not callable, BeautifulSoup

Tags: database, dataframe, csv, beautifulsoup, nonetype

#Below is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/maps/search/dance+studio')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')


results = soup.findall('div','section-result-content')
emails = []
locations = []
websites = []
social_media = []

for result in results:

    location_elem = result.find('span', 'section-result-location')
    location = location_elem.text.strip() if location_elem else ""
    locations.append(location)

    website_elem = result.find('span', 'section-result-action section-result-action-wide')
    website = website_elem.a['href'] if website_elem else ""
    websites.append(website)


data = {'Email': emails, 'Location': locations, 'Website': websites, 'Social Media': social_media}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_csv('dance_studio.csv', index=False)``
```

To explain what happening, I using google map and trying to find website and location of dance studio, When I run it give
`Traceback (most recent call last): File " ", line 10, in <module> results = soup.findall('div','section-result-content') TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

#What I am expecting to give a database,
#dataframe in CSV file of their Website and Location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 10, the method `.findall()` should be `.find_all()`

Comment: The reason why it not working is because of line response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/maps/search/dance+studio')
which is return NoneType object. In other words, I can't figure out why it returns a NoneType object. BTW your answer is not correct but thank you for your time!

Comment: With your code I could in the post I could get response. In the comment, the line is missing http/https:: at the beginning, which is why it throws an exception

Comment: Can you like rewrite the line for me?

Comment: Got it me somewhere